# Words wrap automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:background="@null"
            />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

When I type words more than screen's width, Words wrap to 2 lines. And they changed to one line after I hide the soft keyboard. It is a problem of 'android:fillViewport' or something else?

Comment: In the manifest, try to set this in the Activity tag: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustNothing"`
This will prevent the softkb to resize the views

Comment: @Muddz horizontalscrollview doesnt work after adding that flag